# Print value of function without a variable in C

Tags: c, function, variables, methods, cs50

let's assume the following code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int test (int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
   test(2,3);
}

int test (int a, int b)
{
 int c = a+b;
 printf("%d \n", test(a,b));
 return c;

}
```

why is it not possible to print the value of test without having to save it in a variable before and print the variable? I get the error:

> function.c:12:1: error: all paths through this function will call itself [-Werror,-Winfinite-recursion]

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int test (int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
   test(2,3);
}

int test (int a, int b)
{
 int c = a+b;
 printf("%d \n", test(a,b));
 return c;

}
```

Comment: It is perfectly possible. But your function is infinitely recursing (as your compiler told you). You need a way to *stop* calling `test()`.

Comment: If you ran that program, on a rather large set of possible computer+operating system combinations, you would very probably get a stack overflow due to the infinite recursion.

Comment: Recursive functions need to have one or more base cases that can be solved without recursion and one or more alternative paths which make recursive calls to solve what should be a simpler problem.  You have the recursive calls; you don't have the base case.  And it isn't clear that the recursive call gets you closer to the solution.  Although in some ways it isn't a good example, a recursive factorial function demonstrates the base case (`n <= 1`), and the recursive case (`n * factorial(n - 1)`): `int factorial(int n) { if (n <= 1) return 0; return n * factorial(n - 1); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler message says, the function will call itself, because, in `printf("%d \n", test(a,b));`, the code `test(a,b)` calls `test`. Inside that call to `test`, the function will call itself again, and this will repeat forever (up to the limits of the C implementation).

To print the return value of the function, do it outside the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", test(2, 3));
}

int test(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear.  The test-function calls itself.  And inside *that* call, it calls itself again, (and again, and again...).

It will never complete.

This is a type of infinite loop, commonly called ***infinite recursion***.

Perhaps what you want is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int test (int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
   test(2,3);
}

int test (int a, int b)
{
 int c = a+b;
 printf("%d \n", c); // Show the result of the calculation
                     // but without calling this function again.
 return c;

}
```